# Gettings TypeError

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

When I submit a form request , I am getting an error `[TypeError: object is not a function]` .
Here is my mongoose code : `hiren-conf.js`

```
var auth = require('../auth.js');
var mongoose = require( 'mongoose' );

mongoose.connect(auth['mongodb']);

var authSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    tag: String,
    email: String,
    username: String,
    createdOn: Date,
    updatedOn: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    url: String,
    password: String,
    icon: String
});

var masterPass = new mongoose.Schema({
    hash : String,
    tag : String,
    state: { type: String, default: false}
});

exports.auth = mongoose.model('Auth', authSchema);
exports.master = mongoose.model('Master', masterPass);
```

and `database.js` code :

```
var mongoose = require( 'mongoose' );
var auths = require('../model/hiren-conf');

exports.create = function(req){
    var instance = new auths();
    if(req.body.tag && req.body.email){
        auths.findOne({ 'tag' : req.body.tag , 'email' : req.body.email}, function(err , duplicate){
            if (!err){
                if(!duplicate){
                    instance.tag = req.body.tag;
                    instance.email = req.body.email;
                    instance.username= req.body.username;
                    instance.createdOn = Date.now();
                    instance.url = req.body.url;
                    instance.password = req.body.password;
                    instance.save(function(err){
                        if(!err) console.log('Saved');

                    });
                    return "Save";

            }       else return "Duplicate";
        } else console.log(err);
        });

        }

    };
```

May be there is a problem in `exports.auth` , but I am not sure. Any idea how to solve this ?

Comment: I'd guess the error is thrown from `var instance = new auths();` inside `exports.create`. If `auths` is the `exports` from `hiren-conf.js`, then it won't be a `function`. It'll be an `Object` with `auth` and `master` properties. Maybe try `var instance = new auths.auth();`. Otherwise, what line does the error occur on? The stack trace should include file names and line numbers.

Comment: Tried this too . new error TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'findOne'

Answer (score 0):

To reference the `'Auth'` model, you'll have to access the property, `auths.auth`:

```
exports.create = function(req){
    var instance = new auths.auth();
    if(req.body.tag && req.body.email){
        auths.auth.findOne(...);
// ...
```

---

Since `auths` is the `exports` from `hiren-conf.js`:

```
var mongoose = require( 'mongoose' );
var auths = require('../model/hiren-conf');

// ...
```

It'll be a plain `Object` with `auth` and `master` properties rather a `function` or `Model` itself:

```
// ...

exports.auth = mongoose.model('Auth', authSchema);
exports.master = mongoose.model('Master', masterPass);
```